# why did serverstatus have a bad effect on mongod write operation?

Tags: mongodb

I have 1 mongos, 3 mongod and 3 config server. when I write some documents, sometimes the insert speed of one of mongods is very slow and there're "serverstatus was very slow" in mongod log file. why?

the version is 2.0.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That message actually reflects the fact that your server was slow, not that serverStatus is causing the problem.  If the serverStatus command (which is run periodically by MMS agents for example) is slow, it will log that warning - it is a symptom rather than a cause.

It is quite lightweight as a command, so if it is returning slowly enough to warn you about it then the host is likely very busy at that time.

The usual places to look for load apply (high inserts/updates, table scans, poorly indexed queries, disk issues, RAM/CPU contention, page faults etc.).

Comment: Is it possible for 10gen to improve the error message above? Given the fact that this question even exists, it seems like the log entry could include more clarity.

Comment: Possibly, but if you read the full error message, it literally says something like: serverStatus was very slow: { lots of info about when/where it was slow } - the next line will usually be a summary of the command and how long it took to return.  Interpreting it as the cause of slowness is something of an odd way to look at it - there are likely to be plenty of other messages in there to indicate that there are other issues, and this is just another one of those diagnostic messages.  If you have a suggestion for better/clearer messaging, what would you have it say?

Comment: in my case, I increased the docker memory for mongodb container and all was fine!